# Saving the result of an echo command in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, debian, echo

I am attempting to store the result of an echo command as a variable to be used in a shell script. Debian 4.19.0-6-amd64

The command works in terminal: `echo $HOSTNAME` returns `debian-base`, the correct hostname.

I attempt to run it in a shell script, such as:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

CURRENT_HOSTNAME=`echo $HOSTNAME`
echo $CURRENT_HOSTNAME
```

I have tried expansion:

```
CURRENT_HOSTNAME=$(echo $HOSTNAME)
```

And just to cover some more bases, I tried things like:

```
CURRENT_HOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME
# or
CURRENT_HOSTNAME="$HOSTNAME"
# also, in case a problem with reserved names:
test=$HOSTNAME
test="$HOSTNAME"
```

Works great in the terminal! Output is as follows:

```
root@debian-base:/scripts# echo $HOSTNAME
debian-base
root@debian-base:/scripts# TEST_HOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME
root@debian-base:/scripts# echo $TEST_HOSTNAME
debian-base
root@debian-base:/scripts# TEST_TWO_HOSTNAME=$(echo $HOSTNAME)
root@debian-base:/scripts# echo $TEST_TWO_HOSTNAME
debian-base
```

As soon as I run the script (as above):

```
root@debian-base:/scripts# sh test.sh

root@debian-base:/scripts#
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please do let us know if `echo $HOSTNAME` is working in your script? Without  assigning it to a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `bash` as your terminal. Bash has the variable `$HOSTNAME` set. You run your script with `sh`. `sh` does not have a `$HOSTNAME`.

Options:

```
bash test.sh
```

Or run it as a program:

```
chmod +x test.sh
./test.sh
```

But I think you need to change your first line to:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

As I don't think bash is installed in `/usr/bin` in most cases. But you need to try. To figure out where bash is installed use `which bash`

Another option is to use the `hostname` binary:

```
CURRENT_HOSTNAME=$(hostname)
echo $CURRENT_HOSTNAME
```

Which works in both bash and sh.

You can start `sh` by just running `sh`. You will see it has a bash-like terminal. You can try to do `echo $HOSTNAME`. It will not show, because it's not there. You can use `set` to see all the variables that are there (as `sh` does not have tab completion it's harder to figure out).

Comment: Yes, using `bash` rather than `sh` did the trick!
On Debian, a `which bash` does output `/usr/bin/bash`, so my original shebang does show the correct path. Made the assumption that the shebang would call bash regardless of how it was invoked. Glad I now know.